# How to change the display format of date in a DateTime field in Django?

Tags: django

Im using the django date picker widget with this in `forms.py`:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
input_type = 'date'
```

and using this on the meta class in the modelForm:

```
widgets = {
        'birthdate': DateInput(format=('%Y-%m-%d'),)
    }
```

at first without the format argument on the DateInput widget it just didnt work, now it works but the date is shown in the field with the format 'mm/dd/YYYY' and I want it to be shown with the format 'dd/mm/YYYY'.

Ive tried with the different localization variables on `settings.py`, this is my current configuration:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-MX'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Hermosillo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

the widget works right and the date value is correctly read and saved but i cant get it to be shown with the correct format on the input

Comment: Did you try `%d/%m/%Y` in the widgets dictionary like this: `widgets = {'birthdate': DateInput(format=('%d/%m/%Y'),)}`

Comment: I tried it but it only changes the format that is used to pass the date to the backend I think